# What to do with answers for Pre-1.0 software whose API has changed

Tags: discussion, support

The Meteor framework is going 1.0 shortly, and as one searches for `0.9.4` answers, the answers for `0.6.x` really start to get in the way.

I've heard some suggestions to add `[OUTDATED]` to the question title, but what does the community do by convention when this happens?

Comment: Add a comment? Downvote the answer? It is usually up to the author of the answer to [keep the answer current](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15431343) or add a [big fat version disclaimer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6193082).

Comment: "Keeping the answer current" may not be an option. What if the cause of a problem got fixed in later versions? People may still want to read the old fix, if not for the same, then possibly for *similar* problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Downvote a correct and helpful answers just because it's not applicable to your situation? Do you really want old content to disappear? Adding a version marker would be a useful edit, but that's something anyone running over that question/answer can do, not only the author, we allow editing by the community for a reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've received such downvotes, because the answer and question had no indication of the version. As such, my answer was no longer correct, because visitors rightly assumed that it'd apply to their current installation. Together with a comment, I've found such signals helpful to keep track of what answers are out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the version number to the *question*, not to the title.

I don't think it's wise to add an alternative answer for a newer version, as it would be "Not an Answer" for the *original* question. Rewording the question to match an answer using a newer version should be actively discouraged.

Keep in mind Stack Overflow is a repository of questions-and-answers, and by the practical transient nature of software versions, they are *strongly* linked to a particular version of the used software. An answer to a question on C-89 may not be applicable to C-11. Changing the answer to match *another version* (be it older, newer, or a totally independent fork) is Not An Answer.

There are valid reasons to keep 'outdated' questions *and* answers. Sometimes for historical reasons (one day, hopefully, trying to parse HTML with GREP may throw the hardwired error "Bad usage"), or for legacy software, or because a *similar* scenario may occur in newer versions.