# Updating answers based on ECMAScript 6

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm seeing a growing number of Javascript questions where the answer could/will change when ECMAScript 6 becomes widely adopted.

I see two issues here:

1. For questions based on core javascript principles, with thousands of up-votes on the top answer, it will be hard for new answers to rise to the top and be selected.
2. On old questions the original poster may no longer be active, meaning the correct answer will never be selected.

Is there a recommended way to handle these situations?

Comment: _"When ECMAScript 6 becomes widely adopted"_... That'll take quite a while, still... As such, I don't think this question can reliably be answered yet.

Comment: Related: [What to do with answers for Pre-1.0 software whose API has changed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274383/what-to-do-with-answers-for-pre-1-0-software-whose-api-has-changed)

Comment: A change in technology doesn't mean you need to go back and re-answer all the old questions. New questions that are specific to the new technology should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: Well it's slightly different for JavaScript compared to other languages, as there is no significant compatibility gap between new and old code, unlike (say) Python 2/3. Regardless, I don't think that the old answers will become completely irrelevant, even with increasing support for ES2015.